# Sql trigger checks if age is more then 16

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Using Oracle database , I have created a table :

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYER (
    PID number  NOT NULL,
    FIRSTNAME varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
    SURNAME varchar2(100)  NULL,
    DATEOFBIRTH date  NULL,
    EXPERIENCE integer  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PLAYER_PK PRIMARY KEY (PID)
) ;
```

I would like to make a trigger which will checks the age of player if is more then 16. I have this trigger, it does not work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_DATE_BIRTH
BEFORE INSERT ON PLAYER 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if (extract(year from (sysdate-:new.DATEOFBIRTH) year to month )<16) then
  dbms_output.put_line ('Player must be above 16 years old ');
  rollback;
  end if
END;
/
```

Maybe because I have changed format of the date using

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it have to be a trigger?  A check constraint would be a simpler and faster way to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

The format of the date is irrelevant.  Instead, raise an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_DATE_BIRTH
BEFORE INSERT ON PLAYER 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if (extract(year from (sysdate-:new.DATEOFBIRTH) year to month ) < 16) then
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR -20002, 'Player must be above 16 years old');
  end if;
END;
```

In general, a better way to check for age is not to just use the year.  I would recommend:

```
if add_months(:new.DateOfBirth, 16*12) >= sysdate then
    . . .
```